# Big O with Taylor Series Expansion

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, taylor-expansion

I've plotted the taylor series of $$e^x$$
on WolframAlpha and got the following

[image]

Pretty straight forward, until the very last term
$$O(x^6)$$

Can anyone explain in simple words why it's there and how it was derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Landau or Big-O notation. It simply denotes a "residue" term that is so small in the neighbourhood of $x_0=0$ that the limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}6-\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^5}{120}}{x^6}$$ exists and is some constant $c\in\mathbb R.$ The reason it's denoted by a big $O$ or sometimes $\mathcal O$ is that what it means is that the residue term is "of the order $x^6$". You could rewrite it as $O(x^6)=x^6T(x)$ for some other Taylor series $T$.

Comment: Is it possible to tone down the mathematical concepts and explain in plain english? Would help me understand better :) I already know what Big O is.

Comment: It's there to show that $e^x$ is not a polynomial. The right-hand side would be a polynomial without the big-O term. So $e^x$ can never equal a the right-hand side without it. However, $O(x^6)$ says there is no polynomial that fits $e^x$ better than the one above. Every better polynomial would have to be of at least degree $6$.